# Pull out replaceable fields from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that might contain something along the lines of:

> The {dog} jumped over the {fox}

I need to take this string and get an array which includes "**{dog}**" and "**{fox}**".
 
Are there any regular expression wizards that can help me?

Comment: What did not work with what you tried?

Comment: I did not try anything because regular expression are a pain in the ass. :)

Comment: If it's a pain in the ass, why should we bother doing it for you then? :) StackOverflow is not a code generator service.

Comment: Because someone that knows regular expressions by heart can help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String str = "{dog} and the {cat}";
        String[] ret = ExtractTagValue(str);
    }

    public static String[] ExtractTagValue(String input)
    {
        List<String> retLst = new List<string>();

        String pattern = "(\\{.*?\\})";
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern);

        System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(input);
        if (matches.Count > 0)
        {


            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                retLst.Add(match.Value);
            }
        }

        return retLst.ToArray();
    }
```

Result will be :

{dog}
{cat}